# Read filename from another file, then access the file

Tags: php, file, filesize

What am I doing wrong? I have a prog that writes jpeg-filename to a file called "last_jpeg". I read the filename from that file but I can't access the file with PHP.

```
<?php
$getfilename = file_get_contents('/work/last_jpeg'); // -> '/work/201111091134.jpg'
echo 'File size for '.$getfilename.' is: '.filesize($getfilename);

// Filesize fails because it does not find/can't access the file for some reason?

system('ls -la '.$getfilename);
// Outputs: -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 240425 Nov 9 11:34 /work/201111091134.jpg
?>
```

Thnx for your answers!

- Andy

Comment: `/work/201111091134.jpg` indicates an absolute path from the root of your filesystem. Is this where the file is located? If no, that's your error. If yes, does the php user process have permission to access folders and file?

Comment: use dir() to get the filename. Then once you have it, use file_get_contents. It currently looks as you're using file_get_contents as "dir_get_contents" - ok?

Comment: Yes it is the correct location of that file. Both files 'last_jpeg' and '201111091134.jpg' have the same permissions and owner.

Comment: @user247245 /work/last_jpeg is a file containing a name to another file which I need to access.

Comment: @user247245 That was simple! Thnx a lot.. It works nicely :)

Comment: What are you trying to do ?.   Look at usage of file_get_contents , the echo will contain the contents not the file size.

Comment: Leading/trailing whitespace in the contents of `last_jpeg`???

Answer (score 0):

Try using the url path to get file contents following:

```
$getfilename = file_get_contents('http://www.yoursite.com/work/last_jpeg');
```

OR as:

```
//for > PHP 5
$getfilename = $file = file_get_contents('/work/last_jpeg', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

I Hope it works for you

Comment: Thnx for your answers.. All it needed was some trimming :)